# Как можно улучшить этот код?

Tags: c#, generics, рефакторинг

Интересует улучшение реализации интерфейса IValueChangedEventArgsFactory - класса ValueChangedEventArgsFactory. Возможно ли сделать обобщение? Мои попытки не дают результата. Обязательно не использовать рефлексию.

```
enum DataType
{
  INT16,
  UINT16,
  // И еще типы есть
}

interface IValueChangedEventArgsFactory
{
  IValueChangedEventArgs GetValueChangedEventArgs(string address, DataType dataType, OperateResult oldValue, OperateResult newValue);
}

class ValueChangedEventArgsFactory : IValueChangedEventArgsFactory
{
  private IDictionary<DataType, Func<string, DataType, OperateResult, OperateResult, IValueChangedEventArgs>> factory;

  public ValueChangedEventArgsFactory()
  {
    factory = new Dictionary<DataType, Func<string, DataType, OperateResult, OperateResult, IValueChangedEventArgs>>()
    {
      { DataType.INT16, (string address, DataType dataType, OperateResult oldValue, OperateResult newValue)
        => new ValueChangedEventArgs<short>(address, dataType, oldValue, newValue) },
      { DataType.UINT16, (string address, DataType dataType, OperateResult oldValue, OperateResult newValue)
        => new ValueChangedEventArgs<ushort>(address, dataType, oldValue, newValue) }
    };
  }

  public IValueChangedEventArgs GetValueChangedEventArgs(string address, DataType dataType, OperateResult oldValue, OperateResult newValue)
  {
    factory.TryGetValue(dataType, out Func<string, DataType, OperateResult, OperateResult, IValueChangedEventArgs> func);
    return (func == null) ? throw new NotImplementedException() : func.Invoke(address, dataType, oldValue, newValue);
  }
}

interface IValueChangedEventArgs
{
  string Address { get; }
  DataType DataType { get; }
}

interface IValueChangedEventArgs<T> : IValueChangedEventArgs
{
   OperateResult<T> NewValue { get; }
   OperateResult<T> OldValue { get; }
}

class ValueChangedEventArgs<T> : System.EventArgs, IValueChangedEventArgs<T>
{
  public string Address { get; private set; }
  public DataType DataType { get; private set; }
  public OperateResult<T> OldValue { get; private set; }
  public OperateResult<T> NewValue { get; private set; }

  public ValueChangedEventArgs(string address, DataType dataType, OperateResult oldValue, OperateResult newValue)
  {
    Address = address;
    DataType = dataType;
    OldValue = (OperateResult<T>)oldValue;
    NewValue = (OperateResult<T>)newValue;
  }
}

class OperateResult
{
  public bool IsSuccess;
}

class OperateResult<T> : OperateResult
{
  public T Content;
}

public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    var factory = new ValueChangedEventArgsFactory();
    var oldValue = new OperateResult<short>() { Content = 1 };
    var newValue = new OperateResult<short>() { Content = 2 };

    var args = factory.GetValueChangedEventArgs(string.Empty, DataType.INT16, oldValue, newValue);
  }
}
```

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю вас смущает передача enum в метод GetValue.. ? Теоретически определить тип передаваемого значения можно внутри функции используя оператор is и передача enum, как и он сам будут излишними.

Comment: Нет, меня интересует возможность вызывать интерфейсный метод как обобщённый. Но городить на каждый тип проверку is тип_такой-то не хочу. Для этого я могу и switch по перечислению создать.

Comment: К сожалению такой возможности нет, все обобщения должны быть заданы на этапе компиляции.

Comment: почему `ValueChangedEventArgs` принимает обычный OperateResult и приводит его к обобщенному? Почему сразу обобщенный не принимать? Возможно тогда и factory не нужна будет

Comment: OperateResult - класс внешнего кода. И его возвращают именно как базовый, а не обобщённый. Делать перебор с определением конкретного типа не хочу. И я решил эту задачу, пришлось использовать Ninject.

Comment: @Nova, а как же нежелание использовать рефлексию? :)

Comment: Ну так я же её и не использую. А в Ninject происходит магия :)

Answer (score 0):

В итоге получилось только так.

```
class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new NinjectSettings { InjectNonPublic = true, InjectParentPrivateProperties = true });
            kernel.Load(new Dependency());

            var factory = kernel.Get<IValueChangedEventArgsFactory>("VCEAF");

            var dataType = DataType.UINT16;
            var oldValue = new OperateResult<ushort>() { Content = 1 };
            var newValue = new OperateResult<ushort>() { Content = 2 };

            var ea = factory.GetValueChangedEventArgs(string.Empty, dataType, oldValue, newValue);
        }
    }

    internal interface IGetGenericFactory
    {
        IValueChangedEventArgsFactory GetGenericFactory(string factoryName);
    }

    class Dependency : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<IValueChangedEventArgsFactory>().To<ValueChangedEventArgsFactory>().Named("VCEAF");

            Bind(typeof(IValueChangedEventArgsFactory)).To(typeof(ValueChangedEventArgsGenericFactory<short>)).Named("INT16");
            Bind(typeof(IValueChangedEventArgsFactory)).To(typeof(ValueChangedEventArgsGenericFactory<ushort>)).Named("UINT16");

            Bind<IGetGenericFactory>().ToFactory(() => new GenericFactoryProvider());
        }
    }

    class GenericFactoryProvider : StandardInstanceProvider
    {
        protected override string GetName(MethodInfo methodInfo, object[] arguments)
            => (string)arguments[0];

        protected override IConstructorArgument[] GetConstructorArguments(MethodInfo methodInfo, object[] arguments)
            => base.GetConstructorArguments(methodInfo, arguments).Skip(1).ToArray();
    }

    enum DataType
    {
        INT16,
        UINT16,
    }

    class ValueChangedEventArgsGenericFactory<T> : IValueChangedEventArgsFactory
    {
        public IValueChangedEventArgs GetValueChangedEventArgs(string address, DataType dataType, OperateResult oldValue, OperateResult newValue)
        {
            return new ValueChangedEventArgs<T>(address, dataType, oldValue, newValue);
        }
    }

    interface IValueChangedEventArgsFactory
    {
        IValueChangedEventArgs GetValueChangedEventArgs(string address, DataType dataType, OperateResult oldValue, OperateResult newValue);
    }

    class ValueChangedEventArgsFactory : IValueChangedEventArgsFactory
    {
        private IGetGenericFactory genericFactory;

        public ValueChangedEventArgsFactory(IGetGenericFactory getFactory)
        {
            this.genericFactory = getFactory;
        }

        public IValueChangedEventArgs GetValueChangedEventArgs(string address, DataType dataType, OperateResult oldValue, OperateResult newValue)
        {
            return genericFactory.GetGenericFactory(dataType.ToString()).GetValueChangedEventArgs(address, dataType, oldValue, newValue);
        }
    }

    interface IValueChangedEventArgs
    {
        string Address { get; }
        DataType DataType { get; }
    }

    interface IValueChangedEventArgs<T> : IValueChangedEventArgs
    {
        OperateResult<T> NewValue { get; }
        OperateResult<T> OldValue { get; }
    }

    class ValueChangedEventArgs<T> : EventArgs, IValueChangedEventArgs<T>
    {
        public string Address { get; private set; }
        public DataType DataType { get; private set; }
        public OperateResult<T> OldValue { get; private set; }
        public OperateResult<T> NewValue { get; private set; }

        public ValueChangedEventArgs(string address, DataType dataType, OperateResult oldValue, OperateResult newValue)
        {
            Address = address;
            DataType = dataType;
            OldValue = (OperateResult<T>)oldValue;
            NewValue = (OperateResult<T>)newValue;
        }
    }

    class OperateResult
    {
        public bool IsSuccess;
    }

    class OperateResult<T> : OperateResult
    {
        public T Content;
    }
```

Comment: что-то мне кажется ручная реализация была бы проще намного :)